# Azure Append BLOB equivalent in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage

We are using Azure Append BLOBs today. Is there a similar functionality in S3?
The only info that I found is that there is no such thing in S3, is this really so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 doesn't have an "append" operation.

Once an object has been uploaded, there is no way to modify it in place; your only option is to upload a new object to replace it.